# Core Dump When Retrieving From Templated Queue

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, unique-ptr, coredump

### Background

I want to have a class `MyClass` that stores a queue of different types. To accomplish this, I created an interface `ValueInterface` and a derived class `Value<T>`. I can now store instances of this derived class in `MyClass` with a `queue<ValueInterface>` member variable.

***Note***: For my own purposes, I am purposely trying to keep `MyClass` non-templated, and I want to rely on templated functions.

### Goal

I have the code below which compiles, but running in the test code below causes a core dump. I thought I was careful when using `std::unique_ptr` and made sure to use `std::move` where possible. The `GetValueAndAdvance<T>` function causes the error. Something is wrong when I try to retrieve from the templated queue. I know it's messy and I'm assuming the `static_cast` will work, but **how can I achieve being able to retrieve a `Value<T>` from the `std::queue`, which stores `ValueInterface` ?**

I don't know if the problem lies in `StoreValue` or `GetValueAndAdvance` or if entire design is flawed and not possible in a type sensitive language.

**Usage in a test:**
This is the functionality I want to accomplish. And this is assuming that each `MyClass` will only be used for one type at a time. So let's assume nobody will ever call `StoreValue<int>(4)` and `StoreValue<string>("hello")` on the same `MyClass` object. But for my own reasons, I want to keep `MyClass` non-templated.

```
 MyClass my_class;
 my_class.StoreValue<int>(5);
 int val;
 my_class.GetValueAndAdvance<int>(&val);
 std::cout << "value: " << val; // Should print "value: 5"
```

**Code:**

```
class ValueInterface {};

template <class T>
class Value : public ValueInterface {
 public:
  Value(T val) : value_(val){};
  T get() { return value_; }

 private:
  const T& value_;
};

class MyClass {
 public:
  template <class T>
  void GetValueAndAdvance(T* out_val) {
    if (!queued_values_.empty()) {
      auto unique_value = std::move(queued_values_.front());
      queued_values_.pop();
      auto unique_value_typed = static_cast<Value<T>*>(unique_value.get());
      *out_val = unique_value_typed->get();
      // Prints 0 even though it should return 5 based on the test code (below)
      std::cout << "value: " << unique_value_typed->get(); 
    }
    return;
  }

  template <class T>
  MyClass* StoreValue(const T& value) {
    auto wrapped_value = std::make_unique<Value<T>>(value);
    queued_values_.push(std::move(wrapped_value));
    return this;
  }

 private:
  std::queue<std::unique_ptr<ValueInterface>> queued_values_;
};
```

**A snippet of the error messages**

```
F0418 18:08:57.928949  244111 debugallocation.cc:763] RAW: delete size mismatch: passed size 1 != true size 4
    @     0x7fda024f8a1f  (anonymous namespace)::RawLogVA()
    @     0x7fda024f8525  base_raw_logging::RawLog()
    @           0x42b162  tc_delete_sized
    @           0x40c595  std::default_delete<>::operator()()
    @           0x40c503  std::unique_ptr<>::~unique_ptr()
    @           0x40b552  mynamespace::MyClass::GetValueAndAdvance<>()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem is in `Value` class, where `value_` is defined as a **reference** to a constant value

```
const T& value_;
```

Define `value_` as normal (not reference) value

```
const T value_;
```

and you should get `5` from `std::cout`.

Observe the constructor of `Value<T>`

```
Value(T val) : value_(val){};
```

The `value_` reference is initialized with (bouded to) a **temporary** variable (`val`) that goes out of scope at the end of the contructor.

So `value_` is bounded to a memory that can be reused, so has undefined value.

Comment: Sorry, this did not fix the problem :(
See above, I updated the post to include a snippet of my error messages.

Comment: @user3445268 - maybe there is another problem but is a problem (and removing the reference, print `5` with my compilers); you should propose us a minimal but complete and compilable example that permit us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @max66, I've since done investigating and found that my compiler was a lot pickier than yours. At run time, it didn't know what size object to delete since all I had was a `ValueInterface` object at first. The fix was to add a virtual destructor in the ValueInterface class and override it in `Value`. Nevertheless, removing the reference from value_ also fixed my code.